# Can we use all of the dataset for doc2vec and CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, doc2vec, multiclass-classification

I have a dataset and the task is a multiclass classification. Paragraph vectors represent documents, and a CNN is modeled. For this, I split the dataset as training (75%) and test (25%). For Doc2Vec, the training set is used. Then, the remaining data (test) is **also split into 2 parts** for CNN. But, my question is that can we use all the data for CNN after Doc2Vec?

Answer (score 0):

You "can" use all the data anywhere you'd like.

But for a classification step, if you're evaluating an algorithm & metaparameters, any estimate of the classifier's performance on future (not-yet-seen) data will be better if calculated on some held-back data that didn't influence the training/tuning of the classifier at all.

As `Doc2Vec` is an unsupervised algorithm, and the classic way of training it (with a unique ID per document) doesn't reveal the classification labels to the algorithm at all, it is fairly defensible to use all the texts for training that model step.

For a downstream classification step (such as the "CNN" you mention), you'd hold back some of the data for accurate evaluation. And perhaps if this is an academic project, that'd be the end of your exercise/experiment.

But if actually deploying the system, you'd quite likely then use all data to retrain a model for production deployment – giving up an accurate evaluation in return for an unknown but likely improvement in actual performance against real not-yet-seen inputs.

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you for your reply. This is a part of a study in a course at the university. Actually, when I examine the work of (Le, Q., & Mikolov, T., 2014), in the Sentiment Analysis task with IMDB dataset, they used 75,000 training instances (25,000 labeled and 50,000 unlabeled) and  25,000 test instances, and I am confused. According to your comment, to make sure I understand correctly, I can use all the texts for Doc2Vec, then I should train CNN with the training set of this dataset, and use the test set to evaluate it correctly. @gojomo

Comment: What you "should" do depends on your goals and constraints. Are you saying you're also working on the IMDB dataset? To re-emphasize my prior answer: it can be defensible to use all unlabeled data for an unsupervised step like `Doc2Vec`. But for a supervised classification step, you'd want to hold some back for a fair evaluation. If you were trying to exactly reproduce some other work, you'd follow their practices in choosing how much to hold back.